# How Javascript wait a click function completed then only repeat the same function after user click again?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Below is my `html`, I am doing a simple text base game, the player want to sell their item.

```
<input name="gg1" id="gg1" value="10">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="fastbtn(1);">Sale</a>
<script>
  function fastbtn(sid){
  var aa = jQuery("#gg"+sid).val();
  if(aa > 0){
      aa--;
      jQuery("#gg"+sid).attr("value", aa);
      ajaxget('plugin.php?id=game&do=store&submit=true&timestamp=12345&gg1[1]=1&ggqty[1]=1&formhash={FORMHASH}&fastbuy=true','bbb'); //this is my ajax function -> ajaxget(requesturl,return result to id);
  }
</script>
```

Example, the `value = 10`, but when user click `10` times (fast clicking), the `value` turn to `0`, but my server side only proceess `8` times.

Is it anyway can matched the quantity of click with server side?

In my mind, is it possible the second click of `fastbtn(sid)` can wait until the first click of `fastbtn(sid)`'s `ajaxget` completed then only process?

Comment: Don't update the value until the server has updated the value.

Comment: does `ajaxget()` return promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the ajax network request will take some finite time and clicking rapidly will send cause many request that are not yet processed on server but you are doing `aa--` resulting in disparity

There can be many ways you can solve this easiest being just disable the button while the ajax in pending state this will limit active ajax request at any given point of time to 1

But since you are using anchor tag disabling is not possible but you can use a flag instead (`isPending`)

- So at load we initialize the flag to say *"there is no pending
  request you can proceed"* (**false**)
- When proceed to do ajax we set the flag to say *"Sorry, busy right now
  try again later"* (**true**)
- Once ajax completes we again reset the flag to **false**

So everytime the user clicks we first check "Are we clear" if no we just return from `fastbtn()` without doing anything

Assuming you're using jQuery's get() function for ajax, you can follow this

```
<script>
    var isPending = false
    function fastbtn(sid, t){
        if(isPending)
        return;

        var aa = jQuery("#gg"+sid).val();
        if(aa > 0){
            aa--;
            jQuery("#gg"+sid).attr("value", aa);

            ajaxget('plugin.php?id=game&do=store&submit=true&timestamp=12345&gg1[1]=1&ggqty[1]=1&formhash={FORMHASH}&fastbuy=true','bbb'); //this is my ajax function -> ajaxget(requesturl,return result to id);
        }

        //...
        //..
        //.
    }

    function ajaxget(url){
        isPending = true;
        $.get(url, function(data, status){
           // <--only fires on success
        })
        .done(function() { // <--only fires on success

        })
        .fail(function() {  // <-- only fires on error

        })
        .always(function() {  // <-- this always fires
            isPending = false; 
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Another way could be to put `aa--` in ajax's success callback or in `done()` so `aa` value changes **only when server has recorded** the change and has sent it's confirmation

Comment: Hi, may I know `function fastbtn(sid, t)`, the `t` is for?

Comment: Yes if you had button you could've use `<input type="button" onclick="fastbtn(1, this);">`. Then we can use `this` reference to button to enable/disable it inside `function fastbtn(sid, t){ t.disabled = true; //.. }`